# Embedded component presentation publishing behavior in DD4T

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I have a DD4T website in Tridion 2013.

Few of the components are published using a CT having default dd4t tbbs with type as embedded.

As these components are embedded in number of pages so thought of publishing them directly using embedded dd4t CT instead of publishing each page if the component content changes. Once I unpublish the comp all the pages having it also gets unpublished as per the default behavior.

But today when I published the comp, none of the pages were published and I had to publish each pages since these were unpublished per the above action.

I thought if the pages are getting unpublished then will be published after publishing the comp. Any insight on this please.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a DD4T issue - more like standard Tridion. Do you have any custom resolvers perhaps?

Comment: No resolver. I highlighted dd4t because the CT has default dd4t templates with which the comps are getting published even though it's type is embedded. In standard tridion I believe you can't publish comps dynamically until it's type has been specified dynamic. But here i can publish comps with embedded CT.

Comment: Huh.. I would have thought you'd still have to mark your CT as dynamic for this to work. Since DD4T doesn't mean CPs have to be DCPs. They're still on the page as normal and as far as I know DD4T does not change this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah its added as embedded in the page. Can we publish components dynamically to form DCP without marking it as Dynamic?

Comment: Not without setting it to Dynamic and using "Allow on Page using Dynamic Assembly" or adding a separate CT that is embedded.

Comment: Okay. So I can still publish the comps dynamically using a embedded CT if added as a comp presentation in any page.

Comment: Only if the CT is marked as dynamic.

Comment: But my CT is embedded and still the comps are getting published with that CT and showing a bubble sign.

Comment: Is there another CT which is linked to the same schema which is dynamic? That would explain why your pages don't get published. Have a look in the Broker database at the Component Presentation and ensure it is the same CT.

Comment: You are right, it was published with another dynamic CT and not with the one embedded with the page. But one thing still not clear on how the pages got unpublished by unpublishing the comp.

Answer (score 6):

Tridion will resolve the published items for you and **re**-publish these by default. It won't remove the responsibility for (what it logically assumes) publishing items for the **first** time.

You're stuck with a manual republish but a look into the transaction package will assist in finding what it is you need to {re}publish.

Answer (score 1):

Your component template is probably not marked as embedded, or you've (un)published from a different publication.

When you unpublish the CT, what does it show to be unpublished when you expand the window?